# Angular ng-repeat custom filter 2 jsons

Tags: angularjs, json, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to list in table 2 jsons dependent on each other

1st json "names" :

```
[
        {
            "name": "AAAAAA",
            "down": "False"

        },

        {
            "name": "BBBBBB",
            "down": "45%"
        },
        {
            "name": "CCCCC",
            "down": "12%"
        }
]
```

second json "datas":

```
[
        {
            "data": "AAAAAA"
        }
]
```

Js file:

```
app.service('service', function($http, $q) {
    this.getNames = function() {
       var datas = $http.get('datas.json', {
          cache: false
       });
       var names = $http.get('names.json', {
          cache: false
       });
       return $q.all([datas, names]);
    };
 });

 app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service) {
          var promise = service.getNames();
          promise.then(function(data) {
                $scope.names = data.names.data;
                $scope.datas = data.datas.data;
             })
             .filter('quefilter', function() {
                return function(data) {
                   var filterque = [];
                   angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
                      if (datas[0].data == item.name) {
                         filterque.push(item);
                      } else if (datas[0].data != item.name) {
                         filterque.push("err");
                      }
                   });

                   return filterque;
                };
             });
```

HTML file:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
         <td>{{name.name}}</td>
         <td>{{name.down}}</td>
         <td>{{datas[0].data | quefilter}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So i try to do custom filter which list only `{{datas[0].data}}` next to the same name from `{{names.name}}`. In my table should be AAAAAA next to AAAAAA.
 But my code didn't work.
Thanks for tips and answers in advance!

Comment: A filter is applied to an array. datas[0].data is an element. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
I added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2376/) to clarify

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
            <td>{{name.down}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="record in datas | filter:{data: name.name}">
              {{record.data}}
            </td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that only one element from datas will match an element in names, use find https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

In your case add this function to the scope

`$scope.getTheRightData = name => $scope.datas.map(d=>d.data).find(d=>d===name);`

and use it

```
<td ng-bind="getTheRightData(name.name)"></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elrasco/34f5Lzgd/6/

Answer (score -1):

Filter:

```
.filter('myFilter', function() {

  return function(input, param) {

    var output;

    output = data.map((val) => {
      if (data.name == param) return val;
    })

    return output;

  }
```

At your view:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="name in names | myFilter(datas[0].data)">
         <td>{{name.name}}</td>
         <td>{{name.down}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It happens when you try to be quick. You are right. I've editted my answer.